# Вместо откладки появилась кнопка присоеденить visual studio

Tags: c#, unity3d, visual-studio

Скачал visual studio и unity. Когда создал скрипт на C# и открыл его вместо откладки была кнопка присоеденение, как это исправить?

Comment: Разве это не должно так и быть? "Подключить к юнити" -- как раз отладка. При запущенном юнити он подключиться к нему и при запущенной игре будет останавливаться в точках останова

Answer (score 0):

Если нужна Visual Studio. То чтобы появилась кнопка "откладки" нужно .csproj определнного типа или .sln, который содержит проект исполняемого типа, файл открыть
В общем - жми "Файл" -> "Проект"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И там создавай проект нужного типа.

В юнити тоже надо создать проект
https://russianblogs.com/article/17291932793/

Comment: а как понять какого типа мне нужен проект? Там нет нигде слова unity